# Javascript Finding Any Visible Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way in JavaScript to see if there are any visible elements and then hide them?

I'm trying to avoid a bunch of if statements to check every div I have that needs to be visible/hidden.  Only one div is going to be visible at a time; and I have a dozen or so, which could lead to a lot of if statements.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: <quote>if there is any visible elements and then hide</quote> visible could be some different thinks, do you mean display:none ? visible:hidden? other ?

Comment: When a user clicks on a topic, to the right there is going to be a description of what the user clicks on.  I honestly don't know which I mean.

Comment: Typically the OP already knows what he wants to achieve, has made an attempt at coding it, and comes here when he gets stuck.  How are we supposed to help when you don't even know what you want?

Comment: I know what I want. I have worked on it, tried jquery and javascript, both have failed (it could of possibly been because of a reference issue on them).  I need to hide all elements when one is clicked to become visible.

Comment: Simply hide all elements at first, then show the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

why don't use jquery ?

```
$('element:visible').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: You could just do `$('element:visible').hide()`, unless they need to do other stuff

Comment: jQuery is a tag in the post, the OP never said he/she could not use it.